# Lettuce 6.0.2 with elasticache through wildfly 10(customized for OSGI deployment)

Tags: project-reactor, lettuce, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to deploy the lettuce 6.0.2 on wildfly 10(which is customized to deploy OSGI bundle), which connects AWS elasticache. The connection URL looks as follows:

```
RedisURI redisURI = RedisURI.Builder.redis(configProperties.getProperty("ECclusterhost"), Integer.parseInt(configProperties.getProperty("ECclusterport"))).withPassword(pswdcharArray).withSsl(true).build();
```

The standalone program executes well, but when I tried to deploy on wildfly it gives me following error at the call: `RedisClusterClient.create(redisURI);`

> Caused by: org.apache.felix.log.LogException:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters ... 42
> more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters from [Module
> "deployment.elasticache-1.0.0.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]

The pom.xml has the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
    <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.59.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.59.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.59.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.14.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Since javax.net.ssl is a part of JDK 8, why it is not available at the time of deployment with the wildfly-10. To speed up the response time, I have asked same question at the [lettuce group](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/discussions/1629).

Update:

after few tweaks the original error is gone.
But still OSGI is not able to deploy reactor API, now I am getting following error:

```
ERROR [com.icare.elasticacheclient] (Thread-91) [MSC service thread 1-7] Invocation of 'init' failed.: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link reactor/core/publisher/DirectProcessor (Module "deployment.elasticacheclient-1.0.0.jar:main" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link reactor/core/publisher/FluxProcessor (Module "deployment.elasticacheclient-1.0.0.jar:main" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Processor
```

This is how the import package looks in pom.xml

```
    <Import-Package>
    org.slf4j;version="1.7.7",javax.net.ssl,javax.security.cert
    </Import-Package>
    <Embed-Dependency>lettuce-core,commons-pool2,netty-transport,netty-common,netty-handler,reactor-core,org.reactivestream</Embed-Dependency>
 <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
```

Not sure if there is a problem with OSGI integration of reactor.

Comment: Seems somehow OSGI is not able to understand the dependency of io.projectreactor

Answer (score 0):

After running the marathon for several days, I am able to fix this issue.
One of the reason is the version of log4j2 API, as I was using higher version, but after the version 2.8.2, the log4j-api.jar file contains compiled for Java 9 also and the older version of OSGI is not able understand the split package system. Also somehow javax package is not directly taken from JVM.
My final pom.xml file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>master</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.companyname.projectmaster</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<artifactId>elasticache</artifactId>
<groupId>com.companyname</groupId>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <log4j2Version>2.8.2</log4j2Version>
    <slf4j-api.version>1.7.7</slf4j-api.version>
    <io.netty.version>4.1.59.Final</io.netty.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
           <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
           <version>${io.netty.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
           <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
           <version>${io.netty.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
           <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
           <version>${io.netty.version}</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>blockhound</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.14.RELEASE</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2Version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2Version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- SLF4J Bridge -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2Version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>standalone</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <redisclusterhost>ElasticacheClusterName</redisclusterhost>
            <redisclusterport>6380</redisclusterport>
            <authpassword>password</authpassword>
            <minidleconnection>2</minidleconnection>
            <maxidleconnection>5</maxidleconnection>
            <maxtotalconnection>5</maxtotalconnection>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
                    <Bundle-Activator>com.companyname.ElastiCacheActivator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Bundle-Vendor>Company Name</Bundle-Vendor>
                    <Bundle-Category>osgi</Bundle-Category>
                    <Export-Package>
                        custom packages to be exported
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.slf4j;version="1.7.7",javax.net.ssl,javax.security.cert,javax.management
                    </Import-Package>
                   <Embed-Dependency>lettuce-core,commons-pool2,netty-transport,netty-common,netty-handler,reactive-streams,blockhound,reactor-core,log4j-api,log4j-core</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
            </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <filename>${project.build.finalName}.jar</filename>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <log4j2Version>2.8.2</log4j2Version>
    <slf4j-api.version>1.7.7</slf4j-api.version>
    <io.netty.version>4.1.59.Final</io.netty.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
           <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
           <version>${io.netty.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
           <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
           <version>${io.netty.version}</version>
           <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
           <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
           <version>${io.netty.version}</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
       </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>blockhound</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.14.RELEASE</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>

    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2Version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2Version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- SLF4J Bridge -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2Version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

```
    <profile>
        <id>standalone</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <redisclusterhost>ElasticacheClusterName</redisclusterhost>
            <redisclusterport>6380</redisclusterport>
            <authpassword>password</authpassword>
            <minidleconnection>2</minidleconnection>
            <maxidleconnection>5</maxidleconnection>
            <maxtotalconnection>5</maxtotalconnection>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
                    <Bundle-Activator>com.companyname.ElastiCacheActivator</Bundle-Activator>
                    <Bundle-Vendor>Company Name</Bundle-Vendor>
                    <Bundle-Category>osgi</Bundle-Category>
                    <Export-Package>
                        custom packages to be exported
                    </Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                        org.slf4j;version="1.7.7",javax.net.ssl,javax.security.cert,javax.management
                    </Import-Package>
                   <Embed-Dependency>lettuce-core,commons-pool2,netty-transport,netty-common,netty-handler,reactive-streams,blockhound,reactor-core,log4j-api,log4j-core</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
            </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <filename>${project.build.finalName}.jar</filename>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```